# How to set hostname with salt-cloud command

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, hostname, saltstack

I am using salt-cloud to create new aws instances:

`salt-cloud -p base_ec2_micro test.mydomain.com`

However, the instance gets its ip as hostname. What can I do to set the fqdn as hostname?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the machine hostname or the minon name? Those are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is ancient, but I'm doing this - I believe you have to use a Salt "state" file (.SLS) to apply the state after firstboot:

`salt.grains.core.fqdns()`.

*Return all known FQDNs for the system by enumerating all interfaces and then trying to reverse resolve them (excluding 'lo' interface). To disable the fqdns grain, set enable_fqdns_grains: False in the minion configuration file.*

via: https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/grains/all/salt.grains.core.html